# How to deploy 2 EAR's with Jboss 7.1.1?

Tags: jsf-2, deployment, jboss7.x, ear

I have 2 EAR projects with JSF2.1-Application. How can I deploy 2 EAR's in jboss 7.1.1 Server? The both EAR's should use the same server. Both EAR's contain also similar projects. (I hope no CDI or EJB issues)

Comment: If you know how to deploy the first, do the same for the second one.  EAR will be isolated so if you don try to get them communicating with each other, you shouldn't have issues.

Comment: Thank you! I will try your suggestion !